# Open popups on specific places of an image?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Image in a HTML page. I want to display different information when the mouse is hovering over different areas of that image. For example, I want to display information-1 when the mouse is over point-1 on the image. And when leaving i want the information-1 to hide and when the mouse is hovering over point-2 i want to popup information-2. Is this possible with JS using any kind of library?

Comment: You could accomplish this using CSS hover on the `<area>` tag of an image map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It's possible.
You can approach in 2 ways:

1. [Image Maps](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm) - Just a link with a tutorial
2. Use CSS to positionate transparent elements above the image and show some text when one of this is hovered.

I made [**this pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xboYRj) to show you an example with **method 2**. With method 1 is kinda the same, you just need to change a little bit the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZY0gdtF.jpg" alt="">

  <div class="cloud">
    <p>Hey a cloud!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tree">
    <p>Tree here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grass">
    <p>Green Grass</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.cloud, .grass, .tree').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('p').show();
}, function(){
   $(this).find('p').hide();
});
```

Of course all of this is just a sample. 
While the first method allows you to define a shape, the second doesn't.

Using method 1 will let you define more accurate areas, but it can be hard. Method 2 is simplier but less accurate. Your needs, your choice.

Comment: You could accomplish that fairly simply without JS. In your CodePen, remove the JS and add `div:hover > p {display: block;}` to the CSS. Here is a fork of your pen -> http://codepen.io/techsock/pen/vEomBa