# How to open image maps popup boxes on the left side instead of right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project with Image maps. I am using JavaScript and CSS to create an image area pop-up box. The pop-up boxes currently open on the right side of the image area. I want some of the popup boxes to open on the left side especially the ones where the image area is on the right. How can I do that? Thanks.

Link to my code - https://jsfiddle.net/5zL1ysvt/2/

```js
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
  });
var myData = {
    "left-eye": {
        "title": "",
        "image":"",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum A dolor sin amet. ."
    },
    "mouth": {
        "title": "",
       
        "description": "Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet. Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.vLorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.vLorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet.</p>Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet."
    },
   
};

var areas         = document.getElementsByTagName('area'),
    bubble        = document.getElementById('myBubble'),
    bubbleContent = document.getElementById('myBubbleContent'),
    bubbleClose   = document.getElementById('myBubbleCloseButton');

// On click of an area, open popup
for(var i=0, l=areas.length; i<l; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener('click', openBubble, false);
}

// On click of close button, close popup
bubbleClose.addEventListener('click', closeBubble, false);

function openBubble() {
  var content = myData[this.id];
  bubbleContent.innerHTML = '<h3>' + content.title + '</h3>'
                          + '<img src="' + content.image + '" alt="" />'
                          + '<p>' + content.description + '</p>';
  bubble.style.top = (event.clientY + 10) + "px";                        
  bubble.style.left = (event.clientX + 10) + "px";                        
  bubble.className = 'shown';
}

function closeBubble() {
  bubble.className = '';
}

// Make the image map responsive
imageMapResize();

$.fn.maphilight.defaults = {
fill: true,
fillColor: '1A8782',
fillOpacity: 1,
stroke: true,
strokeColor: '#1A8782',
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWidth: 1,
fade: true,
alwaysOn: false,
neverOn: false,
groupBy: false,
wrapClass: true,
shadow: false,
shadowX: 0,
shadowY: 0,
shadowRadius: 6,
shadowColor: '000000',
shadowOpacity: 0.8,
shadowPosition: 'outside',
shadowFrom: false
}
```

```css
#myWrapper{
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myImage{
  display: block;
}

#myBubble{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: none;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 1.5rem;
}

#myBubble.shown{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
  width:70%;
}

#myBubble.shown:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left:-30px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: solid 15px transparent;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
}

#myBubble img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#myBubbleCloseButton{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1A8782;
}

#myBubbleCloseButton:hover{
  color: #1A8782;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/master/js/imageMapResizer.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.4.0/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>

<div id="myWrapper">

  <img id="myImage" src="http://tinypic.com/images/goodbye.jpg" usemap="#myMap" alt="" class="map" />


  <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
    <area id="left-eye"  coords="118,36,148,80" shape="rect" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <area id="mouth"  coords="121,84,198,118" shape="rect">
  </map>

  <div id="myBubble">
    <div id="myBubbleContent"></div>
    <div id="myBubbleCloseButton">✕</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open popups on specific places of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569070/open-popups-on-specific-places-of-an-image)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thanks.